# Trouble analyzing pickled data in Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have a dataset which I want to analyze (I cant put it here due to its size but I can describe it) its a dictionary in pickled form, which looks like this:

name:(salary: x, bonus: y, email_address: z, etc.)
each name has 21 attributes with 21 values (some are numbers, some are booleans, some are strings)

I have used pandas to store the data in a dataframe

```
df = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')
```

but unlike pandas dataframes which I have manipulated before, I cannot seem to be able to traverse through this one. head() function does not work, keys() does work but it displays only names in the file. Getting other data by specifying name also works (ex. printing `df['john smith']`). I tried doing this to access other data without manually writing all names, but it does not work

```
names = df.keys()
for i in range(len(df.keys())):
    name = names[i]
    print(df[name])
```

I get error saying ''dict_keys' object does not support indexing'. I guess dictionaries cannot be traversed in same way as the array or a list. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Does not work" is a taboo on SO. You _must_ provide the exact complete error message, with all relevant code, for each specific case.

Comment: what is the output of `print(df)`?

Comment: @nijm its a huge dataset, I can provide example for one case: 'METTS MARK': {'salary': 365788, 'to_messages': 807, 'deferral_payments': 'NaN', ....} there are 100+ such names

Comment: @DyZ for using pandas functions it says that 'dict object has no attribute 'foo''.

Comment: Please click `edit` to add required info to the body of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.keys()` returns an iterable that doesn't support indexing. If you want to iterate through a dictionary just iterate through the keys and index the dictionary using them appropriately:

```
for key in df.keys():
    print(df[key])
```

Comment: I'm happy to help. If this solved your question please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks :).